# I am trying to append JQM "pages" to enable me to display an image when the list items are selected

Tags: jquery, html, xml, jquery-mobile

I am trying to append JQM "pages" to enable me to display an image when the list items are selected. So far I can create the "data-role page" and "data-role header" but when I try to create the "data-role content", it doesn't work. When I display the "name" to the console it appears in inverted commas and I'm wondering is this causing the problem as I'm trying to use "name" id to show where I want the  inserted.

hmtl

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="content">
          <div class="content-primary">
            <div data-demo-html="true">
              <ul id="myList" data-role="listview">
                <li></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

xml

```
<LolCatz>
<kitteh>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Ceiling Cat</name>
    <url>http://icanhas.cheezburger.com/tag/ceiling-cat</url>
</kitteh>

<kitteh>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Basement Cat</name>
    <url>http://i191.photobucket.com/albums/z37/beamerpi/TeeSting_s_Stuff/basement-cat-eats-souls.jpg</url>
</kitteh>


<kitteh>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>Monorail Cat</name>
    <url>http://i178.photobucket.com/albums/w263/Laudon1965/MonorailCat.jpg</url>
</kitteh>

<kitteh>
    <id>4</id>
    <name>Laser Kitteh</name>
    <url>http://31.media.tumblr.com/II7NpYhKVobop9l1WLTAmnGMo1_500.jpg</url>
</kitteh>
</LolCatz>
```

js

function xmlParser(data) {
    xml = data;

```
$(xml).find("kitteh").each(function() {
    kitteh = $(this);
    var name = $(kitteh).find("name").text();
    var src = $(kitteh).find("url").text();
    var id = $(kitteh).find("id").text();
    $("#myList").append('<li><a href="#' + id + '">' + name + '</a></li>');

// Append new "pages" after "home" page
$("#home").append(
    '<div data-role="page" id="' + id + '">');
$("#"+id).append(
    '<div data-role="header" id="' + name + '">' + name);
$("#"+name).append (
    '<div data-role="content" id="img_' + name +    '" ><a href="' + src + '</a>');
    console.log (name);     
});
```

}

inspector:

[image: inspector]

console:

[image: console]

Comment: You need to append the pages to the BODY not the #home page $("body").append('<div data-role="page" id="' + id + '">');

Comment: ezanker, I changed the code to .append to body instead but it didn't have any effect on the outcome.

Comment: If you are using the name as a dom element ID, you need to remove or replace the spaces in the string e.g. CeilingCat or Ceiling_Cat, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems in your code.

1. You are creating DOM element IDs from strings that have spaces in the middle.
2. In the page HTML you are creating, you are not properly closing the tags
3. You need to append the new pages to the BODY not the page
4. You need to refresh the listview widget after adding the listitems.

Try:

```
$xml.find("kitteh").each(function() {
    kitteh = $(this);
    var name = $(kitteh).find("name").text();
    var src = $(kitteh).find("url").text();
    var id = $(kitteh).find("id").text();
    $("#myList").append('<li><a href="#page' + id + '">' + name + '</a></li>').listview("refresh");

    // Append new "pages" after "home" page
    var pHTML = '<div data-role="page" id="page' + id + '">';
    pHTML += '<div data-role="header" id="head' + id + '"><h1>' + name + '</h1><a data-rel="back">Back</a></div>';
    pHTML += '<div role="main" class="ui-content" id="img_' + id + '"><a href="' + src + '" >' + name + '</a></div>';
    pHTML += '</div>';
    console.log(pHTML);
    $("body").append(pHTML)
});
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/a2519er3/1/)**

For better performance, create the list and page html in strings and then append them to the DOM once after iterating the XML:

```
var listHTML = '';
var pagesHTML = '';

$xml.find("kitteh").each(function() {
    kitteh = $(this);
    var name = $(kitteh).find("name").text();
    var src = $(kitteh).find("url").text();
    var id = $(kitteh).find("id").text();        
    listHTML += '<li><a href="#page' + id + '">' + name + '</a></li>';

    // Append new "pages" after "home" page
    var pHTML = '<div data-role="page" id="page' + id + '">';
    pHTML += '<div data-role="header" id="head' + id + '"><h1>' + name + '</h1><a data-rel="back">Back</a></div>';
    pHTML += '<div role="main" class="ui-content" id="img_' + id + '"><a href="' + src + '" >' + name + '</a></div>';
    pHTML += '</div>';

    pagesHTML += pHTML;
});

$("#myList").empty().append(listHTML).listview("refresh");
$("body").append(pagesHTML);
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/a2519er3/2/)**

Comment: Wow, that's brilliant ezanker. Thanks a mil. In the second one where you create the list and page html and append them after iterating, would you still do this if reading from a large file?

Comment: @PamelaKeogh, yes, the more items you need to append, the better the second method is as it appends everything in one go.  The appending to DOM is much slower than building strings in memory.

Comment: Hi ezanker. Can I ask you why you needed to create a new var "pagesHTML" to move the contents of pHTML to before appending?

Comment: @PamelaKeogh, I was creating a variable scoped outside of the each loop so that you can keep adding to it through each iteration.  If you created it inside the each(), you would keep overwriting it.